# Setting library directories in configure scripts

Tags: libraries, configure

I want to compile vim on a 64 bit Linux server. On this machine, all basic directories are on a common network drive. 32 bit libraries are stored in `.../lib`, and 64 bit libraries in `.../lib64`.

When I run the `configure` script, it finds that X11 is in `/usr/X11R6`, and adds `-L/usr/X11R6/lib` to the linker flags. Of course it won't compile, because the 64 bit libraries are in `/usr/X11R6/lib64`.

I tried setting the environment variable `LDIRS=-L/usr/X11R6/lib64` before running `configure`. It didn't help, because in the linking phase, it preceded `-L/usr/X11R6/lib` to my `LDFLAGS` variable, so it still wanted to find the library files in the wrong directory.

Is there any way to force the configure script to find library files on a particular location?